# Why there's no linker warning for mixing -fexceptions and -fno-exceptions

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I'm surprised that there's no warning from  <strike>compiler</strike> linker for mixing -fexceptions and -fno-exceptions, or specifically for mixing code with and without unwind tables. I understand there may be infinite legit and/or uncontrollable ways to end up in this state, but I'd rather get early std::terminate() than (*boring test setup follows*) this :

runner.cpp

```
extern void testA();

int main() {
    try {
        testA();
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

testA.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
extern void testB();

struct resA {
    ~resA() { std::cout << "release resA" << std::endl; }
};

void testA() {
    resA a;
    testB();
}
```

testB.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
struct resB {
    ~resB() { std::cout << "release resB" << std::endl; }
};

void testB() {
    resB b;
    throw 42;
}
```

let's compile a.cpp **without** exceptions but the rest **with** exceptions, also link it all together with exceptions:

`clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3 -std=c++1z a.cpp  -fno-exceptions -c
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3 -std=c++1z b.cpp test.cpp  -fexceptions -c
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3 -std=c++1z a.o b.o test.o  -fexceptions`

Output: `release resB`

We've effectively leaked resource A, maybe a huge one and noone has noticed, we can keep running

When everything is compiled with same flags, all resources are cleaned as expected because all unwinding goes correctly

In this case even marking testA as **noexcept** does not lead to termination when 'potentially throwing' testB throws

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the linker is not aware of, nor responsible for, that kind of plumbing.

Comment: The real problem here is that if a compiler is directed to compile C++ code without support for exceptions, the compiler should go "LOL! Wut?", instead of generating broken code. I tried this experiment with gcc. It looks like it quietly accepted the -fno-exceptions parameter, and quietly ignored it. At least the end result was a message from both destructors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik not sure I follow your answer or that you replicated my setup? Compiler should be pretty happy in this test: code that doesn't throw is compiled without exceptions, code that does - with exceptions

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how do you mean? There are endless reasons to generate C++ code without support for exceptions.

Comment: I verified that I cannot replicate your setup with gcc. gcc includes proper support for unwinding exceptions in C++ code, even if you use `-fno-exceptions`. Both destructors fired, when your code was compiled with gcc, despite `-fno-exceptions` for one of the modules. And unless, @SergeyA , one can guarantee that not only just the code your're compiling now, but also any code that this code could possibly call, will never throw an exception, dropping exception support will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, so why? Like I said, this is often the case with, for example, embedded development, so I think you are overgeneralizing. The support for no exception in gcc is there for a reason, and it is usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ABIs make unwind tables optional for certain (common) cases, such as leaf functions that do not change the stack pointer and do not clobber any callee-saved registers.  Therefore, linking code with and without unwind tables is not necessarily a bug.  A link editor cannot easily determine whether unwind tables are missing because they are not required, or missing because the binary was not compiled correctly.

In addition, code can be compiled without exception unwinding support, but with full (even asynchronous) unwinding tables.  These tables are not just used by the C++ implementation for stack unwinding, but also by debugging and performance tools.  Being table to get accurate stack backtraces without having to install debugging information provides substantial value, independent of the programming language or the language subset used.  This is why some GNU/Linux distributions compile all binaries in this way (including C programs), despite the size overhead that incurs.

But you are right, better toolchain diagnostics are worthwhile.  The [annobin project](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=annobin.git) attempts to collect many checks for recommended build flags, but it currently does not cover unwinding information.  It checks for `-fexceptions` because it is pretty much required hardening even for C code if you ever use POSIX thread cancellation handlers (without any actual cancellation happening), due to [GCC PR 61118](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61118#c13).  But there is definitely room for better diagnostics here.  It's something that H.J. LU's GNU property notes could cover, too.